# Logging in ASP.NET Core Main

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi

I've an ASP.NET Core 3 WebAPI with a simple `Main` and a `CreateHostBuilder`.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
   CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

Later logging in my controllers etc. works fine.

But how can I log possible errors in the Main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get get the logger using

```
// Build the host and configurations
var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    // Get the registered logger service
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<YourClassName>>();
    logger.LogInformation("Logger test");
}
// finally run the host 
host.Run();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way.....the advantage to this one is this is a separate logger from the HostBuilder's, so it can log things before the Host is even built. It also can be used throughout the class and outside Main in Program.cs. The disadvantage is it cant use the appsettings.json file to configure it (unless someone can show me how).

```
public class Program
{
    // The Program console apps private logger
    private static ILogger _logger;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Now create a logging object for the Program class.
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder
        .AddConsole()
        .AddDebug()
        );
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        _logger.LogInformation("PROGRAM CLASS >>> The Program Console Class has started...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Net 6.0, this gist works for me https://gist.github.com/filippovd/edc28b511ef0d7dae9ae8f6eb54c30ed

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = LoggerFactory
    .Create(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        // Copy all the current providers that was set within WebApplicationBuilder
        foreach (var serviceDescriptor in builder.Logging.Services)
            {
            loggingBuilder.Services
                .Add(serviceDescriptor);
        }
    })
    .CreateLogger<Program>();
;

// Add services to the container.
logger.LogInformation("Add services to the container...");


// Console
// ....
info: Program[0]
      Add services to the container...
```